# Linear discriminant analysis based on principal components in R

Tags: pca, sampling, lda

I am trying to perform an LDA on the 2 first PCs of the PCA analysis. I want to sample the data to 80% ref and 20% test. I am wondering how I can mention the grouping (by Species).

This is my data: eq_ph1

```
    Species Sex Name    X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
1  caballus   M C031  75.2 68.5 33.0 51.9 33.1
2  caballus   F C037  66.0 59.0 29.0 44.0 30.0
3  caballus   M C038 107.0 98.0 41.0 61.0 45.0
4  caballus   M C039 103.0 95.0 45.0 68.5 45.5
5  caballus   M C041  95.5 84.0 37.0 62.0 40.0
6  caballus   M C047  48.0 41.0 23.3 37.0 25.0
7  caballus   M C072  58.0 53.0 24.0 41.0 25.0
8  caballus   F C081  64.0 57.0 28.0 44.0 28.5
9  caballus   M C086  52.0 46.0 23.8 40.0 24.0
10 caballus   F C087  69.0 61.0 29.0 46.2 30.0
11   asinus   F AD10  66.4 62.5 24.1 37.5 28.2
12   asinus   M AD14  64.0 57.0 22.0 37.0 27.0
13   asinus   F AD21  70.0 63.0 23.0 39.0 27.5
14   asinus   F AD36  76.0 68.0 25.0 39.0 29.0
15   asinus   M AD38  74.0 65.0 22.0 35.3 27.2
16   asinus   F AD39  73.0 66.0 26.0 38.5 29.0
17   asinus   M AD50  92.0 84.0 32.5 55.0 38.2
18   asinus   F AD51  77.0 70.5 26.0 42.0 29.0
19   asinus   M AD52  82.0 76.0 25.8 41.1 32.5
20   asinus   F AD53  59.0 54.0 18.0 30.2 23.0
21   asinus   M AD68  69.1 64.0 22.0 35.1 26.0
22   asinus   M AD71  95.0 87.7 33.0 54.5 37.7
23   asinus   F AD72  95.0 88.0 34.0 53.5 37.5
24   asinus   M AD73  87.3 78.3 31.6 50.0 35.6
25   asinus   F AD74  95.0 86.0 30.8 52.6 37.0
26   asinus   F AD76  61.5 57.0 19.0 31.5 23.7
27   asinus   F AD77  68.0 63.0 21.0 35.9 26.8
28   asinus   M AD78  85.3 78.0 28.5 47.2 35.0
29   asinus   M AD82  66.1 60.5 20.0 32.8 24.1
30   asinus   M AD83  69.0 63.0 21.3 35.1 27.0
31   asinus   F AD84  67.0 61.0 21.1 35.5 26.9
32   asinus   F AD85  64.0 58.5 20.9 35.1 24.5
33    zebra   F ZH17  80.0 73.0 29.0 47.0 30.5
34    zebra   F ZH28  80.0 72.0 31.0 51.0 33.5
35    zebra   M ZH30  84.5 75.5 32.5 49.0 34.0
36    zebra   F ZH33  79.5 70.0 30.0 48.0 32.0
37    zebra   F ZH47  83.0 73.5 30.2 47.0 33.0
38    zebra   F ZZ48  76.5 67.5 30.0 47.0 32.0
39    zebra   F ZZ49  75.0 68.0 29.0 45.0 30.5
40    zebra   M ZH55  80.0 70.0 33.0 50.0 32.5
41    zebra   F ZH56  78.0 69.0 28.5 47.0 31.0
42    zebra   M ZH57  81.5 74.0 31.5 49.0 33.0
43    zebra   M ZZ63  80.0 71.0 30.0 48.0 34.0
44    zebra   F  Z65  78.0 71.0 30.0 47.0 33.0
45    zebra   F ZZ66  78.0 71.0 27.0 42.5 30.5
46    zebra   M ZH67  81.0 74.0 31.0 47.0 31.0
47    zebra   M ZH69  81.0 73.0 31.0 47.2 32.0
48    zebra   M ZZ71  77.5 70.0 31.0 48.3 33.1
49    zebra   M ZH73  78.0 71.0 29.0 46.9 33.0
```

```
ph1.pca <- prcomp(eq_ph1 [, -c(1:3)], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)

sp <- sample(2, nrow(ph1.pca$x), replace = TRUE,
             prob = c(0.8, 0.2))

ref <- ph1.pca$x[sp==1, 1:2]
test <- ph1.pca$x[sp==2, 1:2]

ld <- lda (x = ref, grouping = ???)
```

How can I make the same sampling on the original data eq_ph1?

Many thanks in advance